# Setting caption/rule width in Algorithm2e algs

Tags: captions, indentation, rules, algorithm2e

Many of the algorithms I have with the `algorithm2e` package do not extend across the page width. If I use the package's `boxruled` or `ruled` options, the result is a box or rule that extends the pagewidth with a lot of whitespace on the right side.

I have changed the width of the algorithm itself using `\setlength{\algomargin}{2in}` but this does not have an effect on the width of the rules. The effect is to 'center' the algorithm code, but leave the environment itself the width of the page.

Is there a way to change that without having to squeeze it into a `minipage`?

UPDATE: 
Minimal example:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
\setlength{\algomargin}{2in}
\begin{algorithm}[t]
\caption{NaiveSelect}\label{algo:naive-option}
Some alg step \;
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @lockstep answer, I've created a wrapper environment which allows the minipage width to be specified as an argument.

```
  %adds minipage to inside of algorithms
  \newlength{\tightalgowidth}
  \newlength{\tightalgoremainder}

  % uncomment to use centered floating algorithms
  \newenvironment{tightalgo}[2][]
  {
     \setlength{\tightalgowidth}{#2}
     \setlength{\tightalgoremainder}{\linewidth-\tightalgowidth}
     \begin{algorithm}[#1] }
  { \end{algorithm} }

  \makeatletter
  \patchcmd{\@algocf@start}{%
    \begin{lrbox}{\algocf@algobox}%
  }{%
    \rule{0.5\tightalgoremainder}{\z@}%
    \begin{lrbox}{\algocf@algobox}%
    \begin{minipage}{\tightalgowidth}%
  }{}{}
  \patchcmd{\@algocf@finish}{%
    \end{lrbox}%
  }{%
    \end{minipage}%
    \end{lrbox}%
  }{}{}
  \makeatother
```

Use it like this

```
  \begin{tightalgo}[ht]{0.5\linewidth}
  \caption{NaiveSelect}\label{algo:naive-option}
  Some alg step \;
  Some other \;
  \end{tightalgo}
```

For this result

[image]

Answer (score 4):

In my solution, I use the [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package to patch `\algocf@start` and `\algocf@finish` which are executed at the beginning resp. the end of the internal `algocf` environment. I add a `minipage` of `0.6\textwidth`. An invisible rule with a length of `0.2\textwidth` is used to center the minipage.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@algocf@start}{%
  \begin{lrbox}{\algocf@algobox}%
}{%
  \rule{0.2\textwidth}{\z@}%
  \begin{lrbox}{\algocf@algobox}%
  \begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}%
}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@algocf@finish}{%
  \end{lrbox}%
}{%
  \end{minipage}%
  \end{lrbox}%
}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
% \setlength{\algomargin}{2in}
\begin{algorithm}[t]
\caption{NaiveSelect}\label{algo:naive-option}
Some alg step \;
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a useful work around. I tried and failed to create an alternate algorithm environment using this method which takes width as a parameter (instead of begin fixed for all algorithms). Would you happen to know how this can be done?

Comment: @cheshirekow One could replace the hardcoded values "0.6" and "0.2" in my workaround with macros and redefife those macros mid-document. For better solutions please ask a follow-up question; note that the `algorithm2e` package in general is very hard to patch.

Comment: Got it. Added an answer with the result. Thanks ;)