# Overfull hbox in patched use of algorithm2e environment

Tags: algorithm2e, patching, overfull

I am using the algorithms environment from `algorithm2e` in a modified way with reduced width (following the solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23296/setting-caption-rule-width-in-algorithm2e-algs)), see the MWE below.

This generates an overfull box that I'd like to get rid of. How can I achieve this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}
\SetCustomAlgoRuledWidth{0.6\textwidth}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@algocf@start}{%
    \begin{lrbox}{\algocf@algobox}%
}{%
    \rule{0.2\textwidth}{\z@}%
    \begin{lrbox}{\algocf@algobox}%
    \begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}%
}{}{}
    \patchcmd{\@algocf@finish}{%
    \end{lrbox}%
}{%
    \end{minipage}%
    \end{lrbox}%
}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
    \begin{algorithm}[h]
        \caption{NaiveSelect}\label{algo:naive-option}
        Some alg step \;
    \end{algorithm}
    \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

The logfile says `Overfull \hbox (276.00105pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 24--27`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to fix `\algowidth`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \SetCustomAlgoRuledWidth{0.6\textwidth}%
  \setlength{\algowidth}{0.8\textwidth}%
}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@algocf@start}
  {\begin{lrbox}{\algocf@algobox}}
  {%
   \hspace*{0.2\textwidth}%
   \begin{lrbox}{\algocf@algobox}%
   \begin{minipage}{0.6\textwidth}%
  }
  {}{}
\patchcmd{\@algocf@finish}
  {\end{lrbox}}
  {\end{minipage}\end{lrbox}}
  {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{algorithm}[h]
\caption{NaiveSelect}\label{algo:naive-option}
Some alg step \;
\end{algorithm}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

The value of `\textwidth` is known with certainty at begin document, so it's best to set parameters depending on it at that place.

Using `\hspace*{0.2\textwidth}` is simpler than a rule.

Comment: Thank you, that works like a charm. May I ask how you find out what needs to be set?

Comment: @user279611 Educated guess looking in the package code.